# There are many image file in my drawable directory. Is it bad?

Tags: android, android-studio

In my Android project, I used so many icons, images and SVG resources. In my drawable directory, there are 220-230 file I guess. Is it bad to store too many resources for my app, really I don't know. Thank you for your helpings.

Comment: do you use all of those ?

Comment: Yes, there are 140 icons in my drawable folder. On the other hand, I store mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi resolutions of each asset.

Comment: Its not a problem , just increases the app size . I my self has over 400+ resources in a big production app .

Comment: Okay thank you so much! By the way, I store each photo 5 times in hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi resolutions. Do you think this is true?

Comment: You can use svg format if those drawables are suitable for vector (icons, etc.) In this way, you don't have to keep different files for every resolution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it is fine as long as you use all the drawables, it increases the size of the application. If you want to reduce the size, go through all the images and see if you can reuse a few. e.g suppose you have few logos then try to come up with a single logo to use everywhere to maintain consistency. This is a design perspective actually. So the best way is to consult a designer who will go through the whole app flow and make suggestions for a better user experience. Also just a FYI try to stick to a single theme across the app and to use text view if possible instead of image view to reduce the app size.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's fine, too. But you can try to compress png file by plugin [Biu](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9788-biu/) for optimizing the size of the app

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it is completely fine. But when you are trying this for the production it is better to reduce. Because when the user trying to download an application from playstore definitely he/she will look for the size. if possible reuse the elements. lot of images is not going affect the app performance. My opinion is to delete unused icons and other stuffs.